# Integrating gedit or kate in a Qt Application

Tags: qt, qt-creator, gnome, gedit, kate

I am trying to develop an a simple IDE for programming languages using Qt for my project.This IDE should contain a text editor and should have pretty printing feature in it.So developing a text editor with qt is out of question.

So my question is: Can I integrate gedit or kate text editor in a Qt application.? I am working on a Gnome environment.If this is possible please explain or point to appropriate tutorials.

Programming language:Cuda,Opencl,C,C++

Your help will be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to take a look at QScintilla: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/qscintilla/intro

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it

Answer (score -1):

Try: `Code::Blocks`

It is incredibly powerful IDE, yet lightweight, only 20MB. I use to program in C++ with `opencv`. And if you want to increase even more, you can add several plugins, like: `Eclipse IDE`, but without its 200MB.

Good luck.

Comment: The question was about implementing an IDE, not finding an existing one. (Also, for Qt programming, I think Qt Creator is the superior open source solution, but that's matter of opinion of course.)